# Flutter get a navigation path from widget

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, mobile

i have made a custom button that i want to use for navigation, i've set it so you can call it as a widget and feed it a sting for title and one for the path where its supposed to lead but it doesnt seem to accept the path as a string giving error.

```
class NavigationButton extends StatelessWidget {
  NavigationButton({@required this.path, @required this.btnTitle});
  final String path;
  final String btnTitle;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BouncingWidget(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
      scaleFactor: 1.5,
      child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacementNamed(path);
      },
      child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0 , right: 10.0 , top : 5.0 , bottom: 5.0 ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/home-btn.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
      child: Center(
            child: Text(
              this.btnTitle,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          )
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and then i tried calling it like this

```
 NavigationButton(
                          path: "(context, /gjuhaime)",
                          btnTitle: "Gjuha ime"
                      ),
```

but i keep getting this error
**Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/gjuhaime", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.**

Answer (score 0):

Not really the nicest way to handle navigation, however it should work.

```
 NavigationButton(
                          path: "/gjuhaime",
                          btnTitle: "Gjuha ime"
                      ),
```

if you would like to use context from parent widget, then you need to pass it as separate parameter, not within the "string".

Comment: And what should I be using instead of String?

Comment: If you would like to use context then pass it as context.
However, as far as I could understand it would work for you with example that I wrote above without passing context.